# Cipher Mismatch error - tomcat7 and godaddy certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat, godaddy, tomcat7

(I have asked the same question in stackoverflow as well.)

I am trying to install an SSL certificate in a tomcat server (linux based server). This is a godaddy certificate. Installation is proper and when I check the website with https, it shows the cert is valid, but with some other error:

```
in chrome: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH (The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite. This is likely to be caused when the server needs RC4, which is no longer considered secure.)
in FireFox: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP
```

My server.xml now:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="/etc/tomcat7/mykeystore" keystorePass="password" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA "/>
```

Tried googling and implementing almost all the results I found, but not expected result. Can someone please help me at the earliest.?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The cipher list is broken, you have the same list repeated several times.

Check the [Tomcat wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/SSLCiphers) for the right syntax, and check the [Mozilla wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS) for the ciphers suites you should be using.

You can try

```
openssl s_client -connect yoursite:443
```

to see what's being negotiated, cipher lists specifically.
You can also use the tools in [this repository](https://github.com/mozilla/cipherscan) to perform a more detailed analysis.